# Creating Augmented Reality Application for blackberry10

Tags: augmented-reality, wikitude, blackberry-10

I'm a **BlackBerry native** applications developer. I'm new in BB10 apps development. I'm supposed to create an **Augmented Reality** based application in BB10. I've no idea whether there's any **third party library** available for blackberry10 or not.

I have googled this thing. Have come to know that Wikitude has provided **wikitide-SDK** for Android and iOS; using it, android and iPhone developers can develop AR (Augmented Reality) Apps very easily. News says that Wikitude will release SDK for BlackBerry later this year.

Do anyone know the exact **release date of Wikitide-SDK for BB10**(blackberry) ?

Do anyone have any idea about **any third library** which I can use for developing AR apps for BB10?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of August first, they've made this [press release](http://www.wikitude.com/wikitude-launches-tripadvisor-augmented-reality-app).

Of interest in that press release is this (emphasis added):

> Wikitude’s most recent product launch is the Wikitude SDK, which allows third parties to develop their own AR apps. *The company is also preparing an SDK for BlackBerry® 10*.

However, they not yet provided a timeline.

Edit: this is now available:

http://www.wikitude.com/wikitude-launches-worlds-augmented-reality-sdk-blackberry-10

Comment: +1 for coming back and posting an update that's valuable to those looking at an answer after the original was posted.

Answer (score 1):

Currently i am exploring Wikitude for BB10. I want to know if Wikitude fetch users location in background or not?

Comment: [link](http://forum.wikitude.com/download)  you can download bb10 SDK for wikitude over here. **Example project** is also provided inside the zip file. As a developer we just need to provide the POIs (points of interest) i.e. latitude and longitudes of the location that we want to be tagged in camera view when the device is facing its direction.

Comment: Thanks for reply i get my answer.